# Using jQuery's $.ajax within an angularJS controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, angularjs

How can I use jQuery's $.ajax() function inside an angularJS controller (instead of angularJS built-in $http) so that the $scope values can be accessed from a view/template later?

I have this somewhat minimalistic angularJS controller:

```
function UserCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/admin/user/johndoe').success(function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
    });
}
```

And in the view something like:

```
<h1>Hello, {{ user.Username }}</h1>
```

However, the `<h1>` in the view will be empty on load, altough a `console.log()` in the controller tells me that $scope.user is populated just as I want.

Now, If I replace the `$.ajax()` call with `$http.get()` everything works fine as expected.

I know of `$http` that is angularJS built-in, but since I am not starting from scratch but have already lots of code that uses jQuery throughout, I want to stick to jQuery for $.ajax().

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because using jQuery ajax is out of the world of angular, you need to wrap your $scope assignment inside of

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.user = data;
});
```

Angular's $http comes pre-built with the digest cycle triggering mechanism.