# Using jQuery AJAX GET with AngularJS not updating view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have the following AngularJS controller:

```
function MemberCtrl($scope){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/getmembers",
        type: "get",
        success:function(data){
            $scope.members = data.member_list;
            console.log($scope.members); //works fine
        } 
    });
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
 <div ng-controller="MemberCtrl">
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="member in members">
        <span>{{member.name}}</span>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

As you can see in the first block of code I make a simple AJAX GET to my resource which returns fine in my `console.log()`. However, nothing changes in my view. I'm guessing this is an issue with the `success:` being async, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Thanks for any help!

Carpetfizz

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery's $.ajax within an angularJS controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716822/using-jquerys-ajax-within-an-angularjs-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the built in [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) service.

```
function MemberCtrl( $scope, $http ) {

    $http.get('/getmembers')
    .success(function( data, status, headers, config ) {
        $scope.members = data.member_list;
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly, I will accept in 6 mins when I can.