# load onsen-ui content with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onsen-ui

I just started using onsen-ui in my phonegap app.
the ui is working fine but i do not manage to change the list content stat it would load it from the server with ajax.

```
  module.factory('$data', function() {
  var data = {};

  data.items = [
      { 
          title: 'Item 1 Title',
          label: '4h',
          desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
      },
      { 
          title: 'Another Item Title',
          label: '6h',
          desc: 'Ut enim ad minim veniam.'
      },
      { 
          title: 'Yet Another Item Title',
          label: '1day ago',
          desc: 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.'
      }


  ]; 

  return data;
```

});

my ajax function is:

```
  var request = $.ajax({url: "http://[my-server-address].php",type: "POST",data: {
                     profile-ID : "70",
                     },dataType: "html"});
request.done(function( msg ) {
```

// do something with var msg
                 });
    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {});

Im sure it must be simple,
How do I use the ajax command to load the content of the list.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using $scope.$apply(); after model value change?

It seems that you are using $.ajax() jQuery ajax methods. jQuery Ajax doesn't tell AngularJS model value changes.

So I suggest that:

Use $http() instead of $.ajax or exec $scope.$apply or $rootScope.$apply in the success callbacl of the $.ajax().

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

This post would help you.

[Using jQuery's $.ajax within an angularJS controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716822/using-jquerys-ajax-within-an-angularjs-controller)