# AngularJS using ng-repeat on a $scope array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller that, through Parse, successfully retrieves and pushes an object onto an array as so:

```
var mySite = angular.module('mySite', []);

mySite.controller('listConnectors', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        //Parse.initialize here;
        $scope.array = [];
        var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObject");
        var query = new Parse.Query(TestObject);
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " rows.");
                // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var object = results[i];
                    alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('foo') + " " + object.get('num'));

                    /***** Pushing onto array here *******/
                    $scope.array.push(object);

                }

                console.log($scope.array[0].attributes.foo); //Grabbed what was needed

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
}]);
```

I am then, unsuccessfully, trying to loop and list the "foo" value of every object in the array, as the console.log above shows. However, nothing is outputted. It's as though, possibly, the ng-repeat is not being executed or entered:

```
    <li ng-repeat="eachElement in array">
    <a > {{eachElement.attributes.foo}}</a>
    </li>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Using jQuery's $.ajax within an angularJS controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716822/using-jquerys-ajax-within-an-angularjs-controller)

Comment: have you tried $apply ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it. Thank you Jonathan Lonowski for the comment and link.

I had to wrap the push onto array with an $apply:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.array.push(object);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in your alert statement and inside the ng-repeat directive do not match. Your alert accesses "x.id" whereas your dom binding accesses "x.attributes.id".

If your alert is showing the expected result, you should change the HTML as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="eachElement in array">
<a > {{eachElement.id}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: My 'console.log($scope.array[0].attributes.foo); //Grabbed what was needed' is what I would like to be displayed, I should have removed the alert because it uses Parse methods. Please pay no attention to it. But either way, {{eachElement.id}} doesn't output anything either.

Comment: I had meant to put eachElement.attributes.foo, but that doesn't work either. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Did you try {{eachElement.attributes.foo}} to see if that worked? I know it's not the property you are looking for. EDIT: beat me to it.

Comment: Yeah, nothing is outputted either :(.

Comment: Open up dev tools and look at the dom tree.

Comment: you should be able to see multiple <LI> tags generated. one for every element in the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65382/discussion-between-james-talmage-and-stackpwrequirmentsarecrazy).