# Why are some of my Angular JS data bindings not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on rewriting a site into Angular JS 1.5.7 and the code is not working with some data bindings.

The data binds the first time I fire up the server and serve the files, but if I reload it no longer works on the {{currentWeather.temperature}}

Here are the HTML and JavaScript entries. Please note I have removed API keys but in my local environment the console.log() will show the expected data so I know the API's are working properly.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="background-color:#111111">

<head>
    <title>Your Local Weather</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/weather-icons.css">
    <script src="vendors/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="localWeather" class="body">
    <h1 class="text-primary" id="text-primary-custom" style="text-align: center">Your Local Weather</h1>


    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <p> {{ userAddress.results[2].formatted_address }}
        </p>

        <p>{{currentWeather.temperature}}</p>


    </div>




    <footer>
        <div class="copyright">Copyright 2017, David Taylor Jr.</div>
        <div class="darksky">
            <p>Weather Data provided by <a href="https://darksky.net/dev">Dark Sky</a> <img src="assets/images/darkskylogo.png" alt="Dark Sky Logo" height="28" width="28"></p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('localWeather', []);


var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

    var onAddressComplete = function(address) {
        $scope.userAddress = address.data;

    };

    function success(pos) {
        var crd = pos.coords;
        $scope.coords = crd;

        $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + crd.latitude + ',' + crd.longitude + '&key=API-KEY')
            .then(onAddressComplete);


        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/API-KEY/' + crd.latitude + ',' + crd.longitude + "?units=us",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data) {
                $scope.currentWeather = data.currently;
                console.log($scope.currentWeather);
            }
        });

    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
};


app.controller('MainController', MainController);
```

Here is the console.log data:

```
Object { time: 1486433921, summary: "Mostly Cloudy", icon: "partly-cloudy-night", nearestStormDistance: 30, nearestStormBearing: 278, precipIntensity: 0, precipProbability: 0, temperature: 56.48, apparentTemperature: 56.48, dewPoint: 41.27, 7 more… }
```

Comment: post the console.log data (data)

Comment: when you refresh sir does your `console.log($scope.currentWeather);` works properly?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I added the console.log data

Comment: @pryxen yes, it logs the data properly every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how AngularJs' dirty checking works, I don't believe it will know that your `$.ajax` call has returned and changed data on `$scope`. The reason it could be working sometimes and then not working is because of the order in which the two simultaneous calls return.

If the `$http` call returns after the `$.ajax` call, Angular will run its digest loop and rebind all `$scope` values to the template, including the one changed in the `$.ajax` call. The opposite scenario, in which `$.ajax` returns second does not trigger this digest loop since jQuery is 'outside' of Angular world.

See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716822/using-jquerys-ajax-within-an-angularjs-controller) for combining jQuery with Angular.

Basically you want to call `$scope.$apply();` at the end of your `success` function. See the [AngularJs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) or [this FAQ](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()) about the topic in the AngularJs repository.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        $scope.currentWeather = data.currently;
        console.log($scope.currentWeather);
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: This actually just consoles out:

`Uncaught TypeError: $scope.apply is not a function
    at Object.success (app.js:25)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLScriptElement.c (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLScriptElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)`

Comment: `$scope.$apply`. @davidtaylorjr

Comment: Thanks @yibuyisheng! Bad copy pasta. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use jQuery's `ajax` method to send the request, but the AngularJS's `$http` object.

AngularJS does not check the scope data once in a while. So if you do not use AngularJS's API to do some asynchronous operations, AngularJS can not find out when the scope data changes. Of course you can use AngularJS's `$apply` method to force updating view with scope data, but it is not recommended here.

Comment: I used the `$http` object first, however, I kept getting CORS issues and cannot figure out how to resolve the issue. Do you have any insight on that?

Comment: This another problem: cross domain. There are some solutions. In your situation, you can add the CORS header in the response in your server code. About CORS header, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I've actually read through that a few times and just can't seem to wrap my head around it. I also can't seem to find any good tutorials on it.

Why does the .ajax method work and not $http?

Comment: Oh, you send the jsonp request with ajax, I did not notice this before. So, you should try the [$http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) method. @davidtaylorjr

Comment: I did try `$http.jsonp` last night but when I did it came back with a MIME type error.

Comment: The principle of jsonp is `load a cross domain script`. Since it is load a script, your server's response must have a `content-type` header with the value `text/javascript`.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is why does the jsonp work in Ajax but not in `$http.json`.  Would it not get the same errors in both situations?

Comment: @davidtaylorjr did you read the docs for `$http.jsonp`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp

"Note that, since JSONP requests are sensitive because the response is given full access to the browser, the url must be declared, via $sce as a trusted resource URL."

Comment: When a third party script is loaded to your page, it can do many bad things and it is difficult to limit the script not to do bad things. So it is dangerous, and AngularJS reminds you to ensure the third party resource is safe.